Values within map once selected make all selections disappear
I have the following code:
{getFoodID.map(el => {
  if (el === t.id) {
    let number = "1";
    
    // Get selected data for the current item
    getselecteddata.forEach(el => {
      number = el.Quantity;
    });

    return (
      <>
        <div className="selection-wrapper">
          {/* Quantity Input */}
          <TextField
            required
            value={number}
            InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
            style={{ pointerEvents: 'all' }}
            id="standard-basic"
            label="Qty"
            name="quantity"
            onWheel={(e) => e.target.blur()}
            InputProps={{ inputProps: { min: 1, inputMode: 'numeric' }}}
            className="second-selection-qty"
            onChange={(e) => {
              // Update the quantity in state for the selected item
              quantityfunctionFoods(e.currentTarget.value, t.id, t);
            }}
            type="number"
            variant="outlined"
          />
        </div>

        {/* Radio Button Group */}
        {getselecteddata.map(el => (
          <RadioGroup
            key={el.id}
            value={el.packingLocation || "To Pack"}
            defaultValue="To Pack"
            row
            onChange={(e) => {
              const val = e.target.value;
              // Update the packing location for the current item
              const updatedData = getselecteddata.map((data) =>
                data.id === el.id
                  ? { ...data, packingLocation: val }
                  : data
              );
              const mergedData = [...getalldata, ...updatedData];
              setListUserF(mergedData); // Persist updated data to state
            }}
          >
            {tr?.map((item, i) => (
              <React.Fragment key={i}>
                <FormControlLabel
                  control={
                    <Radio
                      name={`${item.Name} ${item.Weight}`}
                      color="primary"
                      value={`${item.Name} ${item.Weight}`}
                    />
                  }
                  label={item.Name}
                />
                {el.packingLocation === `${item.Name} ${item.Weight}` && (
                  <>
                    <FormControlLabel
                      control={
                        <Radio
                          name={`${item.Name} Option 1`}
                          color="secondary"
                          value={`${item.Name} Option 1`}
                        />
                      }
                      label={`${item.Name} - Option 1`}
                    />
                    <FormControlLabel
                      control={
                        <Radio
                          name={`${item.Name} Option 2`}
                          color="secondary"
                          value={`${item.Name} Option 2`}
                        />
                      }
                      label={`${item.Name} - Option 2`}
                    />
                  </>
                )}
              </React.Fragment>
            ))}
          </RadioGroup>
        ))}
      </>
    );
  }
})}

Within the tr?.map I select a user - but once I choose an option for that user (Option 1 or Option 2) - then it deselects the user and these options are no longer visible. Once I click the user again then the options show.
How do I change this code so the option also remains persistent - as currently when I select an option is deselects the user (and hence these options no longer show).

make "getselecteddata" and "getalldata" camel-case.  also, if those are not functions, but simply storing data, don't prefix with "get".  those won't fix your problem, but you're driving me crazy.
as for your issue, it would help to see the state you are setting with setListUserF, but my blind guess is that there is an issue with your data structure in your onChange handler.  use some console.logs and make sure you are using square brackets and curly brackets correctly.  "mergedData" also looks like it may be using a spread operator on "updatedData" when it shouldn't.  good luck!
